# DialogFragment IllegalStateException when screen goes off

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

First of all, I've read dozens of SO questions and read excellent post by Alex Lockwood about the `IllegalStateException` problems connected with fragment transactions: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html - **tl;dr I've done my homework**

But what I didn't find anywhere is the `IllegalStateException` problem when the screen goes off and we are trying to commit fragment transaction - show `DialogFragment` in my case.

What is exactly happening in my app is reacting to other activity result and later on showing a `DialogFragment`. **As suggested by many SO users, I'm not showing dialog from `onActivityResult` but from `onPostResume` (I've tried also with `onResumeFragments`)** Simplified code looks like this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Timber.i("${this::class.java.simpleName} onActivityResult")
    activityResult = ActivityResult(this::class, requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

override fun onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume()
    Timber.i("${this::class.java.simpleName} onPostResume")
    activityResult?.let { ActivityResultRepository.resultsSubject.onNext(it) }
}

override fun onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments()
    Timber.i("${this::class.java.simpleName} onResumeFragments")
}
```

I couldn't reproduce exception on my device (Mate 20 pro) or on emulator but I'm receiving crash reports from users of my app (0.5% users affected)

My assumption is, my app is trying to show a dialog after screen goes off. Screen going off is an arbitrary event that causes `onSaveInstanceState` method to be called and it can be called right before my `onPostResume` method. **However this is only my assumption!, maybe there is another cause of the exception**

Has anyone experienced similar problems and manage to handle them? I know I can use `commitAllowingStateLoss` but firstly - `show` method of `DialogFragment` doesn't allow to do that, would have to show dialog manually by using `FragmentManager` (don't know if there are any implications), secondly `commitAllowingStateLoss` is generally a bad thing to do

I'm adding crash report although everyone saw it already somewhere :)

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2053)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2079)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:678)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:632)
       at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens a lot. Activity is not in the correct state to show a dialog. You can guard yourself with this:

```
if (!isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()) {
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted @MatPag answer altought I ended up with different solution, so I'm posting it, maybe it will help someone

In my scenario I don't care about savedInstanceState - it's perefectly fine for me to show initial state of an activity when Android is recreating it so I'm passing null to parent onCreate method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(null) 
}
```

Later on, when showing a dialog, I'm catching IllegalStateException that may be thrown, I've created helper method for this:

```
private fun DialogFragment.showAllowingStateLoss(manager: FragmentManager?, tag: String) {
    try {
        this.show(manager, tag)
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity class has method `isFinishing()`, [link to method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isFinishing()). You could easily check:

```
if (!this.isFinishing)
    loadingDialog.show()
```

An example above is opening plain dialog, but you could use it with DialogFragment.